# Getting 403 when using period in Node Express Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I am using a wildcard route to access files in my node app.  Some files start with a period.  In this case I get 403 Forbidden.  Whats the problem with these paths?

Update:

I am using a wildcard route that looks like

```
app.get('/:area/:place/blob*', function (req, res, next) {
```

so a route that is causing problems would be one like

```
/my/area/.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you are using the express static middleware, in which case you can use the `dotfiles` option.

```
express.static( 'path', { dotfiles: 'allow' } );
```

If you're *not* using static middleware, maybe provide a bit more detail (and some code) – and I can try to help you out.

Cheers.

*EDIT*

Still don't know what your callback looks like, but I have to assume you're using `res.sendFile()`. If that's the case, just try

```
res.sendFile( '/my/area/.git', { dotfiles: 'allow' } );
```

If you're not using `sendFile`, please post your entire callback. I'm not sure how Express could be automatically `403`-ing that request.